# How do I study the convergence of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{\frac{i}{t(1-t)}}}{1+t}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Suppose I want to study the convergence of this integral: $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{\frac{i}{t(1-t)}}}{1+t}dt$$

My first approach was to develop the $e^{\frac{i}{t(1-t)}}$ into cos/sin form, thus giving me:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{\frac{i}{t(1-t)}}}{1+t}dt = \int_{0}^{1}\cos(\frac{1}{t(1-t)})dt  + i\int_{0}^{1}\sin(\frac{1}{t(1-t)})dt$$

In both cases, $\cos(\frac{1}{t(1-t)})$ and $\sin(\frac{1}{t(1-t)})$ have no limit whenever $t \rightarrow 0$ or $t \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Did you notice that the absolute value of the integrand is equal to $\frac1{1+t}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\left|\,\frac{e^{\frac i{t(1-t)}}}{1+t}\,\right|
=\frac1{1+t}
$$

Comment: That $i$ in the exponent makes this very clear to me now :D

Comment: So the integral convergence of the interval $]0;1[$?

Comment: @JohnMayne: I am not sure what you are asking. The integral converges by comparing it to $\frac1{1+t}$ on $(0,1)$.